# UserDefinedFunction takes 10 times longer than plain sql query

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

again problems with a user defined function, maybe somebody has an idea.

Calling the function:

`Select * FROM get_process_single_real('Befuellung','P24A2A009','24_NTest','Gewicht');`
takes up to 15 seconds.

Executing the code of the function inline takes a few hundred milliseconds.
(Without the `BEGIN RETURN QUERY ... End` statement)

```
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT
        tb_fixed_station.station_name station_bezeichnung,
        tb_fixed_process.process_name prozess_bezeichnung,
        tb_datas_process_detail.part_identifier werkstueck_ident,
        tb_datas_process_detail.job_identifier job_ident,
        tb_datas_process_detail.created_at zeitstempel,
        tb_param_setparameter.setparameter_name wert_bezeichnung,
        tb_datas_real_detail.real_value wert
    FROM 
        tb_datas_process_detail
    JOIN 
        tb_datas_real_detail ON (tb_datas_real_detail.id_datas_process_detail = tb_datas_process_detail.id)
    JOIN
        tb_param_setparameter ON (tb_datas_real_detail.id_param_setparameter = tb_param_setparameter.id)
    JOIN
        tb_fixed_process ON (tb_datas_process_detail.id_actfixed_process = tb_fixed_process.id)
    JOIN
        tb_fixed_station ON (tb_fixed_process.id_fixed_station = tb_fixed_station.id)
    WHERE
        tb_datas_process_detail.part_identifier = part_id
        and tb_datas_process_detail.job_identifier = job_id
        and tb_fixed_process.process_name = process
        and tb_param_setparameter.setparameter_name = in_setparameter_name
    LIMIT 1;
END;
```

Any hints are appreciated.

The version of the database is:
PostgreSQL 12.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

I've read that UDF tend to be slower but, 10 times is to much.
Is there a way to recompile the execution plan every time the function is called?
I read somewhere about updating statistics as well?

Answer (score 0):

It might well be a case of a suboptimal generic plan being chosen. You can either investigate why the generic plan is bad and try to improve that, or you can tell PostgreSQL to generate a new custom plan every time:

```
ALTER FUNCTION get_process_single_real SET plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan;
```

If my guess misses, you will have to dig deeper. The best way to do that is to activate [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html). Set `shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'`, `auto_explain.log_min_duration` low enough and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on`, and after a restart you will get the execution plan of all slow statements in the log.

You get even better data if you set `auto_explain.log_analyze = on` and `auto_explain.log_buffers = on`, but that will impact your overall performance.

Once you have the execution plan of a slow execution (and some PostgreSQL skills), you should be able to figure out what is going on.

Comment: thanks for the reply. do you have any hints on how to investigate the generic plan. EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYSE do not give me anything.

Unfortunately the ALTER FUNCTION idea does not improve the result.